# Modified bisection formula for deriving implied volatility for a dividend paying american option

Tags: options, implied-volatility, american-options

I am trying to work out the formula for calculating the implied volatility of an american option on a stock paying dividends (discrete payments or annualized yield).

On page 171 of [Haug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786312408)

The following code is provided for the Bisection algorithm, along with the comment: "**With small modifications, the function can also be used to find the implied volatility for American and exotic options**". However, I am unable to find further information in the book (or online), which provides instructions on the required modification(s).

I include the function code below, hopefully, someone may be able to suggest the required modifications:

```
function BisectionAlgorithm(CallPutFlag As String, S As Double, X as Double, T As Double,
                            r As Double, b as Double, cm As Double) As Double
   Dim vLow as Double, vHigh As Double, vi as Double
   Dim cLow As Double, cHigh As Double, epsilon as Double, tempval As Double

   vLow=0.01
   vHigh=1
   epsilon=0.000001
   cLow = GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vLow)
   cHigh = GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vHigh)
   vi=vLow+(cm-cLow)*(vHigh-vLow)/(cHigh-cLow)
   tempval=GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vi)

   While Abs(cm-tempval) > epsilon
       if tempval < cm Then
           vLow=vi
       Else
           vHigh=vi
       End If

       cLow = GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vLow)
       cHigh = GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vHigh)
       vi=vLow+(cm-cLow)*(vHigh-vLow)/(cHigh-cLow)
       tempval=GBlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,b,vi)
   Wend

   BisectionAlgorithm=vi
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is the same, you just need to use appropriate (American/Exotic) pricer instead of black-scholes.